# How do I override the From field in Evolution?

Tags: email, evolution

In other email interfaces (Thunderbird, Gmail) I can send messages from my account (`user@email.com`) but override the `From:` field with another name and address, for example another address I control on the same domain.

How can I do this in Evolution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add *aliases* to your email account as follows:

- From the application menu select Edit > Accounts
- In the Evolution Accounts window, expand the account you want to modify to reveal the "Mail Accounts" node, and expand that to reveal the `imapx+smtp` node
- Edit that node
- Open the "Identity" tab (should be the first tab opened)
- Locate the "Aliases" box at the bottom of the right-hand pane
- Click "Add" to add a new alias

You can enter just an email address to use the same "Full Name":

```
user2@email.com
```

Or you can enter a new name and email address:

```
"User Two" <user2@email.com>
```

Either way, once you click OK and compose a new email, the new alias will appear in the dropdown list for the "From" field.

**References:**

- https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/evolution/issues/13

Answer (score 1):

The same functionality exists as well in Evolution. It is described here:
https://help.gnome.org/users/evolution/stable/mail-composer-from-field-override.html.en

1. Create a new message
2. Activate `From Override Field` via the menu item `View` in the menu bar.
3. Enter the new from address below the ordinary from dropdown.

Comment: Hey, that's great thanks for the tip. Do you happen to know if a way to automate that however ? It would be nice if it automatically used the to: field as a from: in replies when it's my domain